# Find the smallest value of $n$ such that $3n^3-2019$ is a multiple of 2016

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've been struggling with this question for a while.

[image: This is a link to the original question]

So far I've gotten up to n^3 ≡ 1 mod 672 and I am not sure what I can do from here.

Thank you!

Comment: any thoughts about the question?

Comment: This question comes from the [IMO preliminary contest in HK](https://www.hkage.org.hk/file/competitions/4287/Prelim2018.pdf), question 14.

Comment: so the intended question should be positive $n$ and also $3n^3-2019$ is a positive multiple of $2016$.

Comment: I brute-forced the question and got $289$. Not sure if this is the smallest.

Comment: What about $n=1?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic modular arithmetic:
$$\begin{align}3n^3-2019&\equiv 0\pmod{2016} \Rightarrow \\
3n^3-3-2016&\equiv 0\pmod{2016} \Rightarrow \\
3n^3-3&\equiv 0\pmod{2016} \Rightarrow \\
n^3-1&\equiv 0\pmod{672} \Rightarrow \\
(2a+1)^3-1&\equiv 0\pmod{672} \Rightarrow \\
8a^3+12a^2+6a&\equiv 0\pmod{672} \Rightarrow \\
4a^3+6a^2+3a&\equiv 0\pmod{336} \Rightarrow \\
4(3b)^3+6(3b)^2+3(3b)&\equiv 0\pmod{336} \Rightarrow \\
36b^3+18b^2+3b&\equiv 0\pmod{112} \Rightarrow \\
12b^3+6b^2+b&\equiv 0\pmod{112} \Rightarrow \\
12(2c)^3+6(2c)^2+(2c)&\equiv 0\pmod{112} \Rightarrow \\
48c^3+12c^2+c&\equiv 0\pmod{56} \Rightarrow \\
48(4d)^3+12(4d)^2+(4d)&\equiv 0\pmod{56} \Rightarrow \\
(54\cdot 14+12)d^3+(3\cdot 14+6)d^2+d&\equiv 0\pmod{14} \Rightarrow \\
12(2e)^3+6(2e)^2+(2e)&\equiv 0\pmod{14} \Rightarrow \\
(6\cdot 7+6)e^3+(7+5)e^2+e&\equiv 0\pmod{7} \Rightarrow \\
6e^3+5e^2+e&\equiv 0\pmod{7} \Rightarrow \\
\text{min } e&=2 \Rightarrow \\
\text{min } n&=2a+1=\\
&=2(3b)+1=\\
&=6(2c)+1=\\
&=12(4d)+1=\\
&=48(2e)+1=\\
&=193.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $3n^3-2019$ is a multiple of $2016$
iff
$3n^3 \equiv 2019 \equiv 3 \bmod 2016$
iff
$n^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 672$

Write $672=2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$. Then

- $n^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 32$, which happens iff $n \equiv 1 \bmod 32$
- $n^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, which happens iff $n \equiv 1 \bmod 3$
- $n^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$, which happens iff $n \equiv 1,2,4 \bmod 7$

Now use the chinese reminder theorem for each of the three possibilities mod $7$.

Comment: I got up to there but I'm not sure what to do after that.